# Can Device Encryption on Windows 11 Home Prevent Boot From USB?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

I am currently using Bitlocker with TPM and PIN on my Windows 10 Pro machine. I would like to buy a new laptop with Windows 11 Home on it. Since Windows 11 Home Edition doesn't support Bitlocker, I want to ask a safety question about the Device Encryption provided by the Windows 11 Home.

If I turn on Device Encryption, and then I boot a Linux system from USB, can I access the files in the Windows? On my current Windows 10 Pro, even if TPM releases the key, the disk will still not be decrypted without me entering the PIN.

How secure is the Device Encryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Device Encryption is technically more or less the same as BitLocker. BitLocker has a lot more options for corporate use and can be used on individual disks, while Device Encryption will encrypt ALL drives if you have more than one, without exceptions.
In both cases you can still boot from other media, but you will have to supply the password/pin to get at the encrypted disk(s). (Of course: provided your alternate boot OS has provisions for accessing BitLocker encrypted drives.)

Answer (score 0):

When attacked without a recovery key, device encryption will defend against offline access just as Bitlocker would (technology is the same, yes).
[You can use Bitlocker on Home, too: see https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33596/How-to-use-Bitlocker-on-Windows-10-Home.html - your advantage: the recovery key never touches the cloud].